# How to group different static classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I have a templated static class with different specializations, like this:

```
template<typename Parameter >
class MyClass
{};

 template<>
class MyClass<Parameter1>
{
public:
     static constexpr Integer myarray[]={0};
     static constexpr Integer myarraysize=1;    
 };

  template<>
class MyClass<Parameter2>
{
public:
     static constexpr Integer myarray[]={0,1};
     static constexpr Integer myarraysize=2;    
 };
```

Now I would like to group somehow these informations in a new class

```
template<typename MyClass1, typename MyClasses... >
class MyGroupClass{
//do something...}
```

where I could give as variadic template parameters the different classes and then I could access the different static methods.

For example, I would like to to something as `MyGroupClass[n]::myarraysize` to access `myarraysize` related to n-th `MyClass`.

I imagine I could create a tuple (so having `std::get<n>()`), but it is not very clear to me how to do this, since I have no constructors for such single static classes. After all, the classes are static.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? If so, could you please enlighten me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to to something as MyGroupClass[n]:: myarraysize to access myarraysize related to n-th MyClass. I imagine I could create a tuple (so having std::get()),

It seems to me that you have to distinguish two cases.

(1) when the `myarraysize` in the different classes are of **different** types you can create a `std::tuple` of the different sizes an use `std::get()` to extract the values.

By example

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyGroupStruct
 {
   const std::tuple<decltype(Ts::myarraysize)...> tpl { Ts::myarraysize... };

   template <std::size_t N>
   auto get () const -> decltype(std::get<N>(tpl))
    { return std::get<N>(tpl); }
 };
```

Starting from C++14 you can avoid the trailing return type for `get()` and write simply

```
   template <std::size_t N>
   auto get () const
    { return std::get<N>(tpl); }
```

Observe that the `MyGroupStruct::get()` receive the index (`N`) as template parameter. So it needs a compile time known value. This is necessary because the type returned from the template method differ depending from the index so **must** be known compile time.

(2) when all `myarraysize` in different classes are of the **same** type, you can also create a `std::array` of that type; something as

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyGroupStruct
 {
   using myType = typename std::tuple_element<0u, 
      std::tuple<decltype(Ts::myarraysize)...>>::type;

   const std::array<myType, sizeof...(Ts)> arr {{ Ts::myarraysize... }};

   myType & get (std::size_t n)
    { return arr[n]; }
 };
```

Observe that, in this case, the return value for `get()` is ever the same so it can receive a run-time index as (not template) parameter.

The following is a full compiling example for the different-types (tuple based) case

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Par1 {};
struct Par2 {};
struct Par3 {};
struct Par4 {};

template <typename>
struct MyStruct;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par1>
 { static constexpr int myarraysize {1}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par1>::myarraysize;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par2>
 { static constexpr long myarraysize {2l}; };

constexpr long MyStruct<Par2>::myarraysize;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par3>
 { static constexpr long long myarraysize {3ll}; };

constexpr long long MyStruct<Par3>::myarraysize;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par4>
 { static const std::string myarraysize; };

const std::string MyStruct<Par4>::myarraysize {"four"};

template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyGroupStruct
 {
   const std::tuple<decltype(Ts::myarraysize)...> tpl { Ts::myarraysize... };

   template <std::size_t N>
   auto get () const -> decltype(std::get<N>(tpl))
    { return std::get<N>(tpl); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   MyGroupStruct<MyStruct<Par1>, MyStruct<Par2>,
                 MyStruct<Par3>, MyStruct<Par4>> mgs;

   std::cout << mgs.get<0>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.get<1>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.get<2>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.get<3>() << std::endl;

   static_assert( std::is_same<int const &,
                               decltype(mgs.get<0>())>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<long const &,
                               decltype(mgs.get<1>())>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<long long const &,
                               decltype(mgs.get<2>())>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<std::string const &,
                               decltype(mgs.get<3>())>::value, "!" );
 }
```

And now a full compiling example for the equal-types (array based) case

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Par1 {};
struct Par2 {};
struct Par3 {};
struct Par4 {};

template <typename>
struct MyStruct;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par1>
 { static constexpr int myarraysize {1}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par1>::myarraysize;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par2>
 { static constexpr int myarraysize {2}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par2>::myarraysize;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par3>
 { static constexpr int myarraysize {3}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par3>::myarraysize;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par4>
 { static const int myarraysize {4}; };

const int MyStruct<Par4>::myarraysize;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyGroupStruct
 {
   using myType = typename std::tuple_element<0u, 
         std::tuple<decltype(Ts::myarraysize)...>>::type;

   const std::array<myType, sizeof...(Ts)> arr {{ Ts::myarraysize... }};

   myType & get (std::size_t n)
    { return arr[n]; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   MyGroupStruct<MyStruct<Par1>, MyStruct<Par2>,
                 MyStruct<Par3>, MyStruct<Par4>> mgs;

   std::cout << mgs.get(0) << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.get(1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.get(2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.get(3) << std::endl;

   static_assert( std::is_same<int const &,
                               decltype(mgs.get(0))>::value, "!" );
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> how to change the code if I want to access also myarray and not only myarraysize?

With a C-style array is a little more complicated because you can't initialize a tuple of C-style arrays with C-style arrays.

I propose you to use a tuple of **references** to C-style arrays.

So, given some `MyClass`es with only `myarray` (why add the size when you can deduce it?)

```
template <typename>
struct MyStruct;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par1>
 { static constexpr int myarray[] {0}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par1>::myarray[];

// other MyStruct specializations ...
```

you can add a tuple of references (tuple, not `std::array`, because `int[1]`, `int[2]`, `int[3]` and `int[4]` are all different types) and a `std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>` for sizes.

I mean... you can write something as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyGroupStruct
 {
   std::tuple<decltype(Ts::myarray) & ...> const tpl { Ts::myarray... };

   std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> const arr
    {{ sizeof(Ts::myarray)/sizeof(Ts::myarray[0])... }};

   template <std::size_t N>
   auto getArr () const -> decltype(std::get<N>(tpl))
    { return std::get<N>(tpl); }

   std::size_t getSize (std::size_t n) const
    { return arr[n]; }
 };
```

> what does this stand for "const -> decltype(std::get(tpl))"?

`const` is unrelated to `decltype()`.

`const`, after the list of method parameters, say that the method can be used also by constant object because doesn't change member variables.

Regarding `decltype()` look for "trailing return type" for more informations.

In short, for C++11, the idea is that in

```
auto foo () -> decltype(something)
 { return something; }
```

`auto` say "look after -> for the return type" and `decltype(something)` is "the type of `something`"

You can also write

```
decltype(something) foo ()
 { return something; }
```

if `something` is known before the list of function arguments, but the `auto`/`-> decltype(something)` form become useful when `something` contains template parameters

By example

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum (T1 const & t1, T2 const & t2) -> decltype(t1+t2)
 { return t1+t2; }
```

Starting from C++14 the "trailing return type" is less used because you can simply write

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum (T1 const & t1, T2 const & t2)
 { return t1+t2; }
```

because `auto` say to the compiler "deduce the return type from the `return` expression" (so from `t1+t2` in this case.

This avoid a lot of redundancies.

> And can we use "auto" also in C++11?

`auto` as return type? Without trailing return type?

Unfortunately is available only starting from C++14.

Follows another full example with `myarray` and deduced sizes.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Par1 {};
struct Par2 {};
struct Par3 {};
struct Par4 {};

template <typename>
struct MyStruct;

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par1>
 { static constexpr int myarray[] {0}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par1>::myarray[];

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par2>
 { static constexpr int myarray[] {0, 1}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par2>::myarray[];

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par3>
 { static constexpr int myarray[] {0, 1, 2}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par3>::myarray[];

template <>
struct MyStruct<Par4>
 { static constexpr int myarray[] {0, 1, 2, 3}; };

constexpr int MyStruct<Par4>::myarray[];

template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyGroupStruct
 {
   std::tuple<decltype(Ts::myarray) & ...> const tpl { Ts::myarray... };

   std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> const arr
    {{ sizeof(Ts::myarray)/sizeof(Ts::myarray[0])... }};

   template <std::size_t N>
   auto getArr () const -> decltype(std::get<N>(tpl))
    { return std::get<N>(tpl); }

   std::size_t getSize (std::size_t n) const
    { return arr[n]; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   MyGroupStruct<MyStruct<Par1>, MyStruct<Par2>,
                 MyStruct<Par3>, MyStruct<Par4>> mgs;

   std::cout << mgs.getSize(0) << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.getSize(1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.getSize(2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.getSize(3) << std::endl;

   static_assert( std::is_same<std::size_t,
                               decltype(mgs.getSize(0))>::value, "!" );

   std::cout << mgs.getArr<0>()[0] << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.getArr<1>()[1] << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.getArr<2>()[2] << std::endl;
   std::cout << mgs.getArr<3>()[3] << std::endl;

   static_assert( std::is_same<int const (&)[1],
                               decltype(mgs.getArr<0>())>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<int const (&)[2],
                               decltype(mgs.getArr<1>())>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<int const (&)[3],
                               decltype(mgs.getArr<2>())>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<int const (&)[4],
                               decltype(mgs.getArr<3>())>::value, "!" );    
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I still have some issues here.

1) how to change the code if I want to access also myarray and not only myarraysize? Indeed accessing to the size is just one of the action I would like to accomplish.


2) Would you be so kind to clarify the get function for the tuple case?  what does this stand for "const -> decltype(std::get<N>(tpl))"? And can we use "auto" also in C++11?

Comment: @Garo - Answer improved. Hope this helps.

Comment: you have been very clear for everything I asked for. Thanks a lot! I did not know the auto part "look after -> for the return type". Thank you again!